Will I still be able to marry in Slovenia even after my visa expired?
So my partner is a Slovanian citizen and I am from the US. We had in mind to get married but due to complications of paperwork, I won't be able to get married until after my normal 90 day I'm allowed to be here.
Will I still be able to marry?
Will there be consequences?
Any type of info on this topic would be appreciated

I don't know whether Slovenia would allow you to marry there after the expiration of your visa, but have you considered the consequences of remaining in Slovenia past the expiration of your visa?  If it results in a ban, and if that ban would remain in place after your marriage, and if you are planning to live in Slovenia after marrying, you may want to reconsider the plan even if the marriage itself is possible, or apply to extend your visa, or get a new visa, etc.  Also, what kind of visa is it?  If it is a D visa then you ought to be able to stay legally for 90 days after it expires.

(+1) I have no idea about Slovenia but based on experiences in other EU member states, one potential consequence of a period of illegal say is to make naturalization harder, even years later and even if there is a path to go back to legal residence in the meantime. As your US citizenship makes coming back to the Schengen area relatively easy, I would certainly recommend doing anything you can to avoid any overstay.

@phoog It ought to be a long-stay visa, it would be extremely unusual for a US citizen to get any other I think.

@Relaxed indeed, but it is not at all unusual for people to refer to a period of visa-free authorized presence as a "visa," so it seemed worthwhile to ask, because obviously in one case it's quite likely necessary to leave when that expires and in the other it shouldn't be.

I just have the normal 90 day. I would not think of overstaying much, only a month due to being in the process of getting my paperwork done to get married

"I would not think of overstaying much", 'Much' may be your opinion, but you should not foolishly think that any overstay is considered so lightly by the host country (it usually isn't). Consider the consequences. If you want to be together for the rest of your lives - which presumably you do since you're wanting to get married, don't overstay. Not even by a day.
